# Shortest encoding, Hexadecimal

Tags: c#

Hi guys i would like to send the shortest possible string/value.
If i have the following

```
1)l23k43i221j44h55uui6n433bb4
2)124987359824369785493584379
3)kla^askdjaslkd3AS423$#ksala
```

What is the terminology for shortening strings,
Encoding? Encrypting?

At the same time, what is the best method to shorten a string of text, taking into consideration that i have only sms 255 limit

Comment: The phrase you are looking for is possibly "lossless compression".  But this is not possible unless your input data has some known structure.  What is the structure of your input data?

Comment: Your looking for a compression algorithm, I believe huffman is the best for language but your text seems fairly random so something you probably wont get very good compression

Comment: See https://github.com/antirez/smaz

Comment: Do you know ahead of time what strings you are going to be sending? For example, are you only ever going to send those three strings?

Comment: @EricLippert Yes, I'm looking to send a compressed string using GSM & yap, 1) will most probably be the string i'm sending.

Comment: @RainbowHat: And are you in control of the logic (code) in the receiver?

Comment: Then Eric Lippert's answer applies ;-) Just do a lookup on the receiving end

Answer (score 13):

So my first day in prison I was taken to the mess hall for lunch, and I was sitting with a bunch of old guys who had been there for years. One of them stood up and yelled "51!" and sat down, and everyone laughed. A few minutes later another inmate stood up and yelled "96!" and again, everyone laughed.

I asked the old guy next to me what was going on and he explained that they had heard each other's jokes so many times that they had just made a list of them, numbered them, and yelled out the number to save the time of actually telling the joke.

So I stood up and yelled "23!"

Silence.

I sat down.

"Well, some people just aren't good at telling jokes I guess" said the old guy.

---

If you know in advance the strings that you're going to send, you can distribute a list of them ahead of time, and then just send the number of the string.

Answer (score 2):

The term you're looking for is [compression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_compression). Basically, you transform input data into output data that is shorter or of the same length. This will usually work for patterns and repetitions in the data (something like `abcabcabc`) or for a limited alphabet (like in your second example).